# node-imagemagick is not working in react js

Tags: reactjs, image-uploading

I want to resize (reduce the quality) upload image using imagemagick in react side. but it's functions are not working and came errors.

```
var im = require('imagemagick');
im.resize({
                srcPath: event.target.files[0],
                dstPath: 'kittens-small.jpg',
                width:   256
              }, function(err, stdout, stderr){
                if (err) throw err;
console.log('resized kittens.jpg to fit within 256x256px');
              });
```

these errors always come.

```
TypeError: childproc.spawn is not a function
   }
  24 | }
  25 | 
> 26 | var child = childproc.spawn(file, args);
     | ^  27 | var killed = false;
  28 | var timedOut = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `imagemagic` in a browser environment. As mentioned in the modules README its for Node JS.

I guess the code want to spawn a child process from your node process to execute image magic. But because you are in a browser, there is no process to spawn a child from.

To resize image in the browser you may use a `canvas`.